# Can anyone recommend an open source Help Desk application like Zendesk?

Tags: open-source, tool-rec

I'm in the process of building out a website for my freelance services and would like to offer customers the ability to file issues directly through my site in an interface similar to that offered by Zendesk, however I would like to use a free open source alternative that I can host and manage on my server.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

A list of open source help desk software can be found at:
http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/

Also there's a nice review site at http://helpdeskreviews.com/ (features some open-source systems as well)

We tried bugzilla (http://www.bugzilla.org/) but it doesn't really meet our requirements.

It really depends on your requirements. There are a lot of help desk software. Many commercial companies offer free accounts. Zendesk used to offer free account. We used it for a while and then move to another free account provided by http://ihelpdesk.com

Comment: An old one but still a nice tool we have used in the past (php-based, open-source) http://aticket.org/

Answer (score 3):

you can try OTRS (http://otrs.org && http://otrs.com) ; it's free as in beer and free as in speech, licensed under AGPL.

Comment: Perfect! This looks like exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Our software is primarily feedback system, but it can be easily used as help desk. [UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com/) - Free package is available